# Is there a way to tell in the FourSquare documentation which endpoints require an ownership key?

Tags: foursquare

I've tried to use the stats and timeseries endpoints today and in both cases I've been stymied by 'User does not manage venue' error.  Is there a way I can tell from the documentation which endpoints require a user to be a venue manager?

Comment: The documentation is just poorly marked (IMHO) so I ultimately figured this out on my own.  There is a poorly marked 'Filter' row at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the endpoints which require a acting venue manager are listed under the merchant platform:
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants